# My Pygame surface is not getting pushed back down by gravity

Tags: python, pygame, game-physics

I would really like the purple_idle_rect to be able to jump in the air, then get pulled down by gravity. What really happens here is that once I jump, I am stuck in the air then once I press the jump button again I fall. Basically, I need to press the up arrow key twice to fully jump and land on the ground.

```
import pygame

# import n stuff
import pygame
pygame.init()

# Screen and setup
Screen = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 500))

# Velocity
Velocity = 8

# Purple who sleep
purple_sleeping = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("purple_guy_sleeping.png"), (100, 100))
purple_sleeping_rect = purple_sleeping.get_rect(center=(450, 302))

# Purple who stand
purple_idle = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("purple_man_idle.png"), (100, 100))
purple_idle_rect = purple_idle.get_rect(midbottom = (100,360))

# The ground
ground = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("a2889b85d5c7122.png"), (800, 100))
# Main loop
Run = True
FPS = 60
Clock = pygame.time.Clock()
#  All of our keys
pressed_keys = {"left": False, "right": False}

#  Gravity
player_gravity = 0
isJump = False
while Run:
    pygame.display.update()
    Screen.fill("black")
    Screen.blit(ground, (45, 350))
    Screen.blit(purple_sleeping, purple_sleeping_rect)
    Screen.blit(purple_idle, purple_idle_rect)
    Clock.tick(FPS)
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                pressed_keys["left"] = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                pressed_keys["right"] = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP and purple_idle_rect.bottom == 360:
                player_gravity -=20
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                pressed_keys["left"] = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                pressed_keys["right"] = False
            if purple_idle_rect.bottom == 360:
                isJump = False
                if not isJump:
                    purple_idle_rect.bottom = 360
            if purple_idle_rect.bottom < 360:
                isJump = True
                if isJump:
                    player_gravity += 20

    if pressed_keys["left"]:  # == True is implied here
        purple_idle_rect.x -= 10
    if pressed_keys["right"]:
        purple_idle_rect.x += 10
    purple_idle_rect.bottom += player_gravity
    if purple_idle_rect.bottom > 360:
        purple_idle_rect.bottom = 360
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Your jump code is extremely confusing. It might be handy to have a vertical velocity and constantly be adding it to position, while constantly applying gravity to velocity (physics, right?). Then when your user presses the jump button (and the character is at the right y-level), you set the velocity to the arbitrary value you've chosen. EDIT: note that gravity should *never* change, it is constant.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question it should have no more code than the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem by copy-pasting, a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your jump a bit, this is how it works for me:

```
player_gravity = 20
isJump = False
while Run:
    # pygame.display.update()
    Screen.fill("black")
    Screen.blit(ground, (45, 350))
    Screen.blit(purple_sleeping, purple_sleeping_rect)
    Screen.blit(purple_idle, purple_idle_rect)

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                pressed_keys["left"] = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                pressed_keys["right"] = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP and purple_idle_rect.bottom == 360:
                isJump = True
                player_gravity = -player_gravity
            
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                pressed_keys["left"] = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                pressed_keys["right"] = False

    if pressed_keys["left"]:  # == True is implied here
        purple_idle_rect.x -= 10
    if pressed_keys["right"]:
        purple_idle_rect.x += 10
    
    # Set gravity back
    if isJump:
        player_gravity += 1
        if player_gravity >= 20:
            isJump = False

    purple_idle_rect.bottom += player_gravity
    if purple_idle_rect.bottom > 360:
        purple_idle_rect.bottom = 360

    pygame.display.update()
    Clock.tick(FPS)
```

Perhaps you understand everything well, if you do not ask in the comments. I hope I helped you, Adam